# Setting CSS property trough PHP post method

Tags: php, css, post

I'm trying to dynamically set CSS properties. But for some reason doing it using a post method doesn't work.

**This works:**

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css", 
    "Location:   http://localhost/template/index.php"); 
     $backgcol = '#333';
?>

body
{
  background-color:<?=$backgcol?>;
}
```

**But this doesn't work:**

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css", "Location: http://localhost/template/index.php"); 
     $backgcol = $_POST['color'];
?>

body
{
   background-color:<?=$backgcol?>;
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="style.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="color"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Set color">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the second example have you seen what is the output generated with view-source ?

Comment: What sense it the `Location` supposed to make in that context? You are telling the browser that the content it wants is located somewhere else … so outputting style sheet data after that doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: Fabrizio:
In the second example output is css style sheet. It shows css value set to what I want but it doesn't redirect back to index.php nor does it work on index.php. It's as if index isn't linked to style at all.
CBroe: I use it to redirect back to index.php

Answer (score 0):

You are misuderstanding on too many points.

- See **[PHP Manual - header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)**. Second argument usage is different from what you are considering. At least it should be called repeatedly:

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/css');
header('Location: http://localhost/template/index.php');
```

- `Location` header has nothing to do with CSS file requests.
- `$_POST` value is no longer set on CSS file requests.
- `$_POST` variable is temporary on each request. It cannot be saved.

---

Valid Example:

**setcolor.php**

```html+php
<?php
    const COLOR_REGEX = '/\A#(?:(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}+|AliceBlue|AntiqueWhite|Aqua|Aquamarine|Azure|Beige|Bisque|Black|BlanchedAlmond|Blue|BlueViolet|Brown|BurlyWood|CadetBlue|Chartreuse|Chocolate|Coral|CornflowerBlue|Cornsilk|Crimson|Cyan|DarkBlue|DarkCyan|DarkGoldenRod|DarkGray|DarkGreen|DarkKhaki|DarkMagenta|DarkOliveGreen|DarkOrange|DarkOrchid|DarkRed|DarkSalmon|DarkSeaGreen|DarkSlateBlue|DarkSlateGray|DarkTurquoise|DarkViolet|DeepPink|DeepSkyBlue|DimGray|DodgerBlue|FireBrick|FloralWhite|ForestGreen|Fuchsia|Gainsboro|GhostWhite|Gold|GoldenRod|Gray|Green|GreenYellow|HoneyDew|HotPink|IndianRed|Indigo|Ivory|Khaki|Lavender|LavenderBlush|LawnGreen|LemonChiffon|LightBlue|LightCoral|LightCyan|LightGoldenRodYellow|LightGray|LightGreen|LightPink|LightSalmon|LightSeaGreen|LightSkyBlue|LightSlateGray|LightSteelBlue|LightYellow|Lime|LimeGreen|Linen|Magenta|Maroon|MediumAquaMarine|MediumBlue|MediumOrchid|MediumPurple|MediumSeaGreen|MediumSlateBlue|MediumSpringGreen|MediumTurquoise|MediumVioletRed|MidnightBlue|MintCream|MistyRose|Moccasin|NavajoWhite|Navy|OldLace|Olive|OliveDrab|Orange|OrangeRed|Orchid|PaleGoldenRod|PaleGreen|PaleTurquoise|PaleVioletRed|PapayaWhip|PeachPuff|Peru|Pink|Plum|PowderBlue|Purple|RebeccaPurple|Red|RosyBrown|RoyalBlue|SaddleBrown|Salmon|SandyBrown|SeaGreen|SeaShell|Sienna|Silver|SkyBlue|SlateBlue|SlateGray|Snow|SpringGreen|SteelBlue|Tan|Teal|Thistle|Tomato|Turquoise|Violet|Wheat|White|WhiteSmoke|Yellow|YellowGreen)\z/i';
    function h($str) {
        return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    }
    $color = (string)filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'color');
    if ($color !== null) {
        if (preg_match(COLOR_REGEX, $color)) {
            file_put_contents('color.dat', $color, LOCK_EX);
            $msg = 'Color setting has been saved: ' . $color;
        } else {
            $msg = 'Color format is invalid:' . $color;
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php">
    </head>
    <body>
<?php if (isset($msg)): ?>
        <p><?=h($msg)?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="color"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Set color">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.php**

```css+php
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
$color = is_readable('color.dat') ? file_get_contents('color.dat') : "#ffffff";
?>
body {
    background-color: <?=$color?>;
}
```